# Tuple unpacking into multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the following longstring:

```
emails = '''
CoreyMSchafer@gmail.com
corey.schafer@university.edu
corey-321-schafer@my-work.net
'''
```

From this string, using regular expression, I want to extract the local part, the domain and the main domain into three lists

With the following code:

```
pat = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*)(@[a-z-]+)(.\w+)')
matches = pat.findall(emails)
```

I got the following list, with individuals tuples inside:

```
[('CoreyMSchafer', '@gmail', '.com'), ('corey.schafer', '@university', '.edu'), ('corey-321-schafer', '@my-work', '.net')]
```

If I then unpack the tuples with:

```
local_part, domains, main_domains = zip(*matches)
```

I will get three tuples with the individual elements separated, as shown below:

```
('CoreyMSchafer', 'corey.schafer', 'corey-321-schafer') # local parts
('@gmail', '@university', '@my-work') # domains
('.com', '.edu', '.net') # main domains
```

None the less, I would like to have three lists instead of three tuples.

I have tried the following:

```
a,b,c = map(list,zip(*matches))
```

But I then got the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-73e06f3c6d27> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b,c = map(list,zip(*matches))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: you have some variable `list` shadowing `list` built-in type

Comment: Makes sense, since it runs smoothly for me. And that "list" variable is a list as well.